# cv::remap (in opencv) and interp2 (matlab)

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am trying to look for an equivalent opencv function for interp2 and I understand that 
`cv::remap` is a good way of doing this.

However, if I have the following:

`f2 = interp2( x, y, f, x2, y2, 'bicubic' );`

where `x, y, x2` and `y2` are all (say m x n) matrices, I am not sure how to use `cv::remap` for this.

How would I use `remap` for this? I know I have to convert it to a map ... but I'm unable to do so.

And,is there anything else that could do `interp2` the way the matlab function does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you didn't find your answer yet, this is how you should use it.

```
remap(f,f2,x2,y2,CV_INTER_CUBIC);
```

The function remap supposes that you're working on exactly the grid where f is defined so no need to pass the x,y monotonic coordinates. I'm almost sure that the matrices cannot be CV_64F (double) so, take that into account.

Comment: I couldn't get the same result as matlab gives to me, I'm still trying to figure it out,(I'm working on a project to convert matlab code to opencv code I need same result in opencv to take another step)

Answer (score 0):

interp2 is interpolator - if you get x,y and f values for some mesh it gives you the value f2 for x2 and y2.

remap - wraps your mesh by moving x and y coordinates acording to the deformation maps.

if you want interpolate regular mesh then use scaling (cv::resize  for example).

If data is scattered then you can use Delaunay triangulation and then barycentric interpolation as variant or  [inverse distance weighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting).

Comment: I used `interp2` in matlab to warp one image to another given rotation and translations matrices. Now, I'm trying to do the same in opencv

Comment: Then may be you need http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpaffine warpAffine or warpPerspective function?

Comment: The difference between my warp and `warpAffine` is that warpAffine stretches the image while mine shrinks it given a matrix A (rotation) say [4,0; 0, 4]

Comment: May be I does not completely understand your problem (it hard for me without any pictures), but have you try use optional flag WARP_INVERSE_MAP that means that M is the inverse transformation?