# Matlab Interp2 function behaviour differently compared with OpenCV Remap

Tags: matlab, remap

I am trying to look for an equivalent OpenCV function for interp2 and I refer to this poster to use remap function in OpenCV.

[cv::remap (in opencv) and interp2 (matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912234/cvremap-in-opencv-and-interp2-matlab)

However, I realized that there is a significant difference of the output between these two functions. Here is my Matlab Code

```
U = [0.1 0.1 0.1; 0.2 0.2 0.2; 0.3 0.3 0.3];
X = [0 0 0; 0.5 0.5 0.5; 1 1 1];
Y = [0 0.5 1;0 0.5 1;0 0.5 1];
V = interp2(U,X,Y,'linear',NaN)
```

I get the output V matrix as

```
   NaN       NaN       NaN
   NaN       NaN       NaN
   NaN       NaN    0.1000
```

This is my OpenCV code

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cv.h"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //generate flowmap model
    CvFileStorage* fx = cvOpenFileStorage("result.txt", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE);//ask storage for save file
    Mat xmesh = cvCreateMat(3, 3, 5);
    Mat ymesh = cvCreateMat(3, 3, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < xmesh.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < xmesh.cols; j++)
        {
            xmesh.at<float>(i, j) = i*0.5;
            ymesh.at<float>(i, j) = j*0.5;
        }

    //generate optical flow folder
    Mat u = cvCreateMat(3, 3, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i <u.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < u.cols; j++)
        {
            u.at<float>(i, j) = (i + 1)*0.1;
        }
    Mat v = Mat::zeros(u.size(), u.type());

    remap(u, v, xmesh, ymesh, INTER_LINEAR, 0, cvScalarAll(0));

    //convert mat to Iplimage
    IplImage* xmesh_a = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)xmesh);
    IplImage* ymesh_a = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)ymesh);
    IplImage* u_a = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)u);
    IplImage* v_a = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)v);

    //save end to txt
    cvWrite(fx, "xmesh", xmesh_a, cvAttrList());
    cvWrite(fx, "ymesh", ymesh_a, cvAttrList());
    cvWrite(fx, "u", u_a, cvAttrList());
    cvWrite(fx, "v", v_a, cvAttrList());
    cvReleaseFileStorage(&fx);

    waitKey();

}
```

The output V matrix I get is

```
1.00000001e-001, 1.50000006e-001, 2.00000003e-001,
1.00000001e-001, 1.50000006e-001, 2.00000003e-001,
1.00000001e-001, 1.50000006e-001, 2.00000003e-001
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In the case that `U` holds your data, isn't the function call like this: `interp2(X,Y,U,...)`?

Comment: @Irreducible Thanks for the reply but I think it makes no difference for grid interpolation. Read this poster   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235379/how-to-do-grid-interpolation-interp2-in-opencv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in the results is related to difference in indexing between c++ and MATLAB that is 0-based and 1-based respectively.

`interp2(U,X,Y,'linear',NaN)` is the same as `interp2(1:3,1:3,U,X,Y,'linear',NaN)` changing it to `interp2(0:2,0:2,U,X,Y,'linear',NaN)` you will get the same result as OpenCV.

If you want result of `remap` to be the same as that of `interp2` you can shift the `xmesh` and `ymesh` one step back and search for negative locations to produce `nan` values.

```
#include <cmath>
//...
//...
for (int i = 0; i < xmesh.rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < xmesh.cols; j++)
    {
        xmesh.at<float>(i, j) = i*0.5-1;
        ymesh.at<float>(i, j) = j*0.5-1;
    }
//...
//...
remap(u, v, xmesh, ymesh, INTER_LINEAR, 0, cvScalarAll(NAN));
```

Result:

```
nan nan nan 
nan nan nan
nan nan 0.1
```

Comment: Thanks! @rahnema1 Can you show me how to modify OpenCV code to realize the same result compared with Matlab function? Thanks!

Comment: I mean, if I want to change OpenCV code to realize what the orignial interp2 function does in Matlab, I need to use grid value which is outside of my current grid, right? Do I need to paddle my xmesh and ymesh using NaN at this point? I am trying to paddle NaA but don't know how to assign a NaN value in OpenCV.

Comment: You need to shift the grid one step back. I mean `for (int i = -1; i < xmesh.rows-1; i++) for (int j = -1; j < xmesh.cols-1; j++)` and include `<cmath>` and set the last parameter of the `remap` function to `NAN`.

Comment: I changed my OpenCV code but still didn't get the same results. It would be great if you can post the modified OpenCV code so that I can test it. I appreciate your help and will accept answer once I get the identical results.